# Why do I keep getting CORS errors even though I've configured it correctly

Tags: vue.js, asp.net-core, .net-core, fetch, asp.net-core-webapi

So I've developed a client using Vue, and for the backend I'm using ASP.NET Core Web API.
I have a form on the client and when I click the button to submit the form to the server the error occurs.

If I open Visual Studio and run the project on "https://localhost:44393" and I serve the client on "http://localhost:8080/"
everything works just fine, I have no issues posting the form at all.

However.. If I then publish the Web API to where I'm hosting it which is over at smarterasp.net and change the fetch from

```
fetch("https://localhost:44393/Account/AddServer", {
        ..
```

to

```
fetch("https://api.mywebsite.com/Account/AddServer", {
        ..
```

It throws this error in the Google Chrome console

```
Access to fetch at 'https://api.mywebsite.com/Account/AddServer' 
from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: 
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. 
If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

Okay, now you might think that I shouldn't try to access it from "http://localhost:8080". Fine, I'll just upload the files to my webserver over at namescheap
then it throws this error

```
Access to fetch at 'https://api.mywebsite.com/Account/AddServer' 
from origin 'https://mywebsite.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: 
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. 
If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

And that's the only endpoint that does this, posting or getting on other endpoint doesn't throw any errors.

**QUESTION**
Why is it only throwing the errors when calling the API after it's been published, and not when the API is running locally? The only difference between the forms is that this form that I'm using that throws the exception uses `enctype="multipart/form-data"`

Here is the action that it's calling

```
[EnableCors("AllowEverything")]
[Authorize]
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult AddServer(ServerModel server)
{
    var username = User.Identity.Name;

    /* Validate data */
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var httpRequest = HttpContext.Request;
        //var files = httpRequest.Form.Files;
        //return Ok();
        ///*If the user added a banner*/
        if (httpRequest.Form.Files.Count() > 0)
        {
            using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                httpRequest.Form.Files[0].CopyTo(ms);
                var fileBytes = ms.ToArray();
                ImageExtParser iep = new ImageExtParser(fileBytes);
                var type = iep.CheckFileType();
                if (type == null)
                {
                    return BadRequest(Json("Invalid banner image."));
                }

                var bannerName = Guid.NewGuid() + "." + type;
                server.Banner = "banners/" + bannerName;

                FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create($"ftp://myftpserver.com" + bannerName);
                request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
                request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("myUsername", "hidingthecredentialsobviously");

                using (Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
                {
                    requestStream.Write(fileBytes, 0, fileBytes.Length);
                }

                using (FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
                {
                    var k = response.StatusCode;
                }
            }
        }


        if (_dbContext.Servers.Where(x => x.IPHost == server.IPHost).FirstOrDefault() == null)
        {
            server.Owner = username;

            /* */
            if (_dbContext.Servers.Where(x => x.IPHost == server.IPHost).FirstOrDefault() != null)
            {
                return BadRequest(Json($"Server with IPHost {server.IPHost} has already been added."));
            }

            server.Tags = "test";
            _dbContext.Servers.Add(server);
            _dbContext.SaveChanges();
            return Ok();
        }
        else
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("IPHost", " already exists.");
            return BadRequest(Json(ModelState));
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return BadRequest(Json(ModelState));
    }
}
```

ConfigureServices (I'm allowing everything for testing purposes)

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddCors(options =>
    {
        options.AddPolicy(name: "AllowEverything",
                      builder =>
                      {
                          builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                                 .AllowAnyMethod()
                                 .AllowAnyHeader();
                      });
    });
```

Configure

```
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseRouting();

app.UseCors("AllowEverything");

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
```

JavaScript

```
postData(e) {
  let formData = new FormData();
  formData.append("Name", name);
  formData.append("IPHost", iphost);
  formData.append("Country", country);
  formData.append("Description", descripton);
  formData.append("Banner", document.getElementById("bannerup").files[0]);

  fetch("https://api.mywebsite.com/Account/AddServer", {
    method: "post",
    body: formData,
    headers: new Headers({
      Authorization: "Bearer " + this.getCookie("Bearer"),
    }),
  })
    .then((res) => {
      if (res.ok) {
        document.location = "/Profile";
      }
      return res;
    })
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((vals) => {
      console.log(vals);
      for (var key in vals) {
        this.addError(key, vals[key]);
      }
    });

  e.preventDefault();
}
```

Comment: Try to remove from the action [EnableCors("AllowEverything")]

Comment: That didn't change anything unfortunately

Comment: It's quite possible that your ASP.NET Core API throws an exception when it's published. This usually means the CORS headers don't get set, so check your server logs to see if there's any sign of an exception.

Comment: @KirkLarkin That sounds like something that could be the case, I remember getting this error when I was getting an exception locally yesterday, I'll check it out

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not on Back-end part, its chrome not allowing to fetch https on localhost

just add

```
{
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
}
```

in fetch headers

Comment: yes, pretty similar to that, but Headers is just an object not a class example, here`s example code
https://hatebin.com/wbvnjolbkc